# Regular graph with no non-trivial automorphim

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am looking for a regular graph example which has no automorphism other than identity (trivial).

I tried for complete graphs, cycle, and some more regular graphs, but they are not the valid examples. I am looking for an easy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One construction for cubic graphs is to draw a tree with all vertices of valency one or three in the plane, then draw a cycle through the vertices of degree one. This gives you a planar cubic graph and, provided your initial tree is large enough, it is not hard to produce graphs witn no non-identity automorphisms. And the point is that you can verify by hand
that your graph is asymmetric. (These graphs are sometimes referred to as *Halin graphs*.)

You can also use Latin square graphs, but now you need a computer to determine the automorphism group. Here the vertices are the $n^2$ position in an $n\times n$ Latin square, and two positions are adjacent if they are in the same row, the same column, or if they have the same entry. You'll need $n\ge 5$ to have a chance of an asymmetric graph, but for large $n$ most choices work. (Don't choose the multiplication table of a group!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For planar cubic graph, how much big should be the initial graph?

Comment: @xyz - I'm pretty sure you can do it with 12 vertices.

Answer (score 5):

The Frucht graph on 12 vertices is 3-regular and is asymmetric.

See the Wikipedia articles on "Frucht graph" and "asymmetric graph".  The smallest asymmetric regular graphs have 10 vertices.